# Jersey REST service throw Timeout exception

Tags: java, rest, jersey, spring-rest

we have a Jersey REST service, and REST client using Spring's REST template, once in a while we noticed the client got 500 Internal Server Error from the REST service:

```
error: 500 Internal Server Error; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
```

when checking the server's log we found this:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ABC] in context with path [] threw exception [javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
```

I'm not sure what the problem is here, is the server timeout or the client got timeout? If it's client issue, i can add retry, but what to do if it's server timeout?

Answer (score 1):

The error `Connection timed out`: means that your request did not get a response within the specific time or in time period. and there is many  reasons for time out our response bot get in time period:

1) may be ip address or port is incorrect.

2) may be ip address is down.

3) you server or host is taking longer or more time than your specify time for timeout.

4) may be  firewall  of server or host  blocking the requests or port which you are using.

5)  internet access or local network issue or connectivity.

6) packet loss due to wrong network configuration or traffic overload.

c) overloading of too many requests issue at host or server .